# Is there any ways for transfer from RDBMS to HDFS besides SQOOP?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

1. I want other way than by using sqoop for transfer RDBMS to HDFS please give me clue
2. Please anyone explain to me, whats the relation between hive and sqoop?

Comment: It would be good if you share which particular RDBMS are you talking about.

Comment: MySql database to hadoop dev

Comment: There are lots of option - use `spark`, `apache-drill`, `apache nifi`, etc. you can do it manually - use `mysqldump` to convert to csv and then put csv in hadoop

Answer (score 1):

Added to  dev ツ's answers you have one more tool called streamsets data collector which help you to get data from mysql to HDFS by creating JDBC connection.